# Multiple types for each record in Neo4j.rb

Tags: neo4j.rb

I have a database currently represented as a set of YAML files (one record per file). I would like to port it into Neo4j. Each record has a property "type" which stores an array of types. I would like to have a module (that includes `ActiveNode`) for each type. Each node object would then extend the modules corresponding to its types. The only way I can think of to implement this with neo4j.rb is to generate a class for each existing combination of types and include the corresponding type modules in the class. Is there some better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

More concrete examples might help.  Is there a natural hierarchy to the types?

Class hierarchy for multiple labels has been supported for a while, but I just put in some changes to the master branch in the last couple of days to make it work more smoothly.  You should be able to do something like this:

```
class Person
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
end

class Author < Person
end

class Collaborator < Person
end

class Software
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
end

class Application < Software
end

class Library < Software
end
```

If you did `ChildType.create` it would create a node with both the `ParentType` and `ChildType` labels.  If a query loads a node with both labels, the `ChildType` model class will be used.

We've also talked about the ability to load modules to do multiple labels, though we weren't able to think of a good example, so I'd welcome one.

Comment: Thanks for your response Brian. My types do not have a hierarchy, so I would be very happy if you implemented the ability to associate modules rather than classes with labels. As for the example, the database I'm using is a kind of personal external brain. I represent all kinds of entities in this database-- two very different kinds of entities are people and software, and in both cases I have the need for this feature. A person may have types of "author", "collaborator", "friend" etc. Some software might have both "application" and "library".

Comment: ...{continued from previous comment} ... Since different kinds of information needs to be associated with each type, they have different required fields.

Comment: Ah, I see, but they all seem to be types of `Person` in your example, so I could certainly see those as subclasses.  I updated my answer to reflect that, but if that's not quite right feel free to drop by our Gitter chat room: https://gitter.im/neo4jrb/neo4j?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge

Comment: Agreed that collaborator and author are both people, but the problem is that a person can be both a collaborator and an author (and innumerable other things)-- just as a piece of software can be both an application and a library. Hence the lack of natural hierarchy at a certain level.

Comment: Ah, very true.  We should probably dig into this further.  We have an issue open for it here: https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/543 which I've just updated with a link to this question.  I'll discuss it with my colleague and we'll see what we can do.  I can think of a couple of ways to go about it